# Flex item disappears when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, dom-manipulation

I am trying to create a site that lets you save passwords. I am trying to use flexbox for this. I have a flex item on the left for the user to create categories to sort the password in and a list of passwords on the right flex item. I wanted to test out if the flex item worked, so I tried to make the button the user created make a h1 element with the text "games" on the right flex item. When I clicked on the user created button, the right flex item disappeared entirely.

```js
//close button for gui that appears for naming a category
const closeButton = document.querySelector('#close-button')
//left flex item
const newFileBox = document.querySelector('#box-1')
//opens the naming new category gui
const folderButton = document.querySelector('#new-folder-button')
//creates the button
const createFolder = document.querySelector('#fileForm')
//list under the add category gui that displays the category buttons
const fileList = document.querySelector('#file-list')
const input = document.querySelector('#file-name')
//right flex item
const flex2 = document.querySelector('#box-2')
let tab = '';




closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    newFileBox.style.display = 'none';
})

folderButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    newFileBox.style.display = 'block';
})

createFolder.onsubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    tab = createFile(input.value)
    tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const item = document.createElement('h1')
        item.innerHTML = 'Games'
        item.appendChild(flex2)
    })
}

function createFile(text){
    
    const file = document.createElement('button')
    file.innerHTML = text;
    fileList.appendChild(file);
    return file;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PassVault</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Display:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 class = 'font'>PassVault</h1>
            <p class = 'font'>A secure place to store your passwords.</p>
            <a href="generator.html" class = 'font'>Password Generator</a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
                    <button id="new-folder-button">Create new folder</button>
                    <div id="box-1">
                        <form action="" id = 'fileForm'>
                            <button type="button" id="close-button">X</button>
                            <label for="file-name">What would you like to call this file?</label>
                            <input type="text" name="file-name" id="file-name">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create file name." id='createFolder'>
                        </form>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <ul id="file-list">

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item flex-item-2" id="box-2">
                </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css code**

```
.font{
    font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 4px solid crimson;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.flex-item-1 {
    min-height: 300px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#new-folder-button {
    color: teal;
    background-color: aqua;
    align-self: center;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 184px;
    font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
}

#new-folder-button:hover {
    color: aqua;
    background-color: teal;
}

#file-list {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}

.files {
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
}

.flex-item-2 {
    min-height: 300px;
    flex-grow: 4;
    width: 100%;
}

.info {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

#box-1{
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Red Hat Display', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}

#close-button {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    border: none;
}

#close-button:hover {
    color: rgb(240, 109, 109);
}
```

I tried to check the console for errors, but there was nothing. I then tried to look for my problem on the internet, and found nothing. I have little experience in javascript, so forgive me if this code looks very sloppy.

Comment: Its working fine. I don't understand whats the issue. Furthermore, the css is also missing. If you add it, I think I could also see the issue. But currently its working fine

Comment: edited this to show my css code